# Trial Version: Downloaded Enterprise version 6x and each time got Professional - help!

Tags: enterprise, trial

I think this is a known issue, as there is much about it online.  Their offices are closed until Monday.  Does anyone know if I work on a build of the Professional site, it will all delete when I have sfdc fix the issue and put me on the Enterprise trial on Monday morning?  I don't want to work all weekend for a demo only to have to start over due to a version problem.  Thanks!

Comment: This is about salesforce and downloaded metadata ?

Comment: Yes...about downloaded metadata.

Answer (score 5):

There is no necessity that a trial PE org has to be deleted when converted to EE. Customers upgrade from PE to EE all the time, and they do not have to start over. So you're probably fine.

An alternative is to sign up for a free Developer Edition, which has all the EE features. Do your work. When you're done, use the workbench or the Force.com IDE to export your work and import into a new org.